# MySQL Not starting with MAMP

Tags: mysql, database, mamp, mamp-pro

I know this might seem a duplicate, but I am struggling.

I managed to start and run Apache and MySQL for one session using MAMP.  Come to it again, MySQL will not start.

I have tried various answers on Stack.  Reinstalling / moving directories / making sure things are update.  The one thing I haven't done, is renaming the 'ib_logfile' - because they are not there!

Anyone have any suggestions?

```
2017-09-23 20:44:46 7fffa5a753c0  InnoDB: Operating system error number 2 in a file operation.
InnoDB: The error means the system cannot find the path specified.
InnoDB: If you are installing InnoDB, remember that you must create
InnoDB: directories yourself, InnoDB does not create them.
InnoDB: Error: could not open single-table tablespace file ./mysql/slave_worker_info.ibd
InnoDB: We do not continue the crash recovery, because the table may become
InnoDB: corrupt if we cannot apply the log records in the InnoDB log to it.
InnoDB: To fix the problem and start mysqld:
InnoDB: 1) If there is a permission problem in the file and mysqld cannot
InnoDB: open the file, you should modify the permissions.
InnoDB: 2) If the table is not needed, or you can restore it from a backup,
InnoDB: then you can remove the .ibd file, and InnoDB will do a normal
InnoDB: crash recovery and ignore that table.
InnoDB: 3) If the file system or the disk is broken, and you cannot remove
InnoDB: the .ibd file, you can set innodb_force_recovery > 0 in my.cnf
InnoDB: and force InnoDB to continue crash recovery here.
170923 20:44:46 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.pid ended
```

Comment: It would be helpful to see your working my.cnf or similar config file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far I got it working - I change the permissions for the Mysql folder in Mamp to read and write and all the containing folders and it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

1. go to /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/ and add new file mysql.pid
2. restart mamp